# Server returns Code: InternalServerError when using CreateUploadSesssion to upload a file

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

My application can upload files into OneDrive, SharePoint normally by Consecutive Upload.
For now, It is broken, and throw InternalServerError when calling

```
var uploadSession = await graphClient.Drive.Items["01KGPRHTV6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"].ItemWithPath("_hamilton.png").CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();
```

I implement follow:
[https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Requests/Functional/OneDriveTests.cs][1]

Exception:

```
Status Code: InternalServerError
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InternalServerError
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
request-id: b3ab4fbb-e3c2-4e07-a353-4e2a73b5bf67
date: 3/10/2020 4:25:56 AM
ClientRequestId: b3ab4fbb-e3c2-4e07-a353-4e2a73b5bf67

at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
```

SDK: Microsoft.Graph 1.21.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We also got the same issue, but it seems that it's an issue with the Graph API that (probably) changed today (2020-03-10). Someone has filed a github issue at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/646 which you can follow, but if you really have to make this work, you can hack around it by overriding the request url using reflection.

```cs
var regex = new Regex(@"/microsoft\.graph\.createUploadSession$");
var reqUrl = uploadSessionReq.RequestUrl;
typeof(DriveItemCreateUploadSessionRequest)
    .GetProperty(nameof(DriveItemCreateUploadSessionRequest.RequestUrl))
    .GetSetMethod(nonPublic: true)
    .Invoke(
        uploadSessionReq,
        new[]
        {
            regex.Replace(reqUrl, "/createUploadSession")
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas. The issue in github was created by me. And now, the issue was fixed by owning team.